# Passing a variable through a method in Java

Tags: java, swing, variables, methods, jbutton

I'm here to ask a little help with a problem I've had for many hours.

In practice, I would like to be able to pass the variables 'j' and 'k' through a method in a matrix. The problem lies in passing them, which, without understanding the reason, are not "captured" when they enter the if. In fact, if I try to print 'r' and 'c' before the if, they match. I do not understand where I'm wrong, because the other things inside the if work perfectly, but when I try to print 'r' and 'c' inside the if, they always turn out to be 0.

Buttons creation :

```
Integer[] x = {10, 70, 130, 190, 250, 310, 370}; Integer[] y = {80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380};
    for (int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0; i < 42; i++, j++) {
        if (j % 7 == 0 && i != 0) { j = 0; k++; }
        lblCircles[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("vuoto.png")));
        lblCircles[i].setBounds(x[j], y[k], 50, 50);
        lblCircles[i].setName("vuota");
        lblCircles[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                            if (e.getSource() == lblCircles[i] && choose == 1) lblClickedPlayer(lblCircles[i], j, k);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCircles[i]);
    }
```

The method :

```
public void lblClickedPlayer(JLabel lbl, int r, int c) {
    if (n == 0 && "vuota".equals(lbl.getName())) {
        n = 1;
        lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("red.png")));
        lbl.setName("piena");
        tbl[r][c] = 1;
        System.out.println("tbl[" + r + "][" + c + "] = " + tbl[r][c]);
    } else if (n == 1 && "vuota".equals(lbl.getName())) {
        n = 0;
        lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("yellow.png")));
        lbl.setName("piena");
        tbl[r][c] = 2;
        System.out.println("tbl[" + r + "][" + c + "] = " + tbl[r][c]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Code for a test :

```
public class Prova {
public JFrame frame;
public JLabel[] lblCircles = new JLabel[42];
public String hostname;
public Font big = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18);
public Integer[][] tbl = new Integer[6][7];
public int choose = 1, n = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Prova window = new Prova();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    });
}

public Prova() { initialize(); }

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    baseFrame(frame, 430, 510);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 7));
    panel.setBackground(new Color(41, 41, 41));
    panel.setBounds(10, 80, 410, 350);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    Integer[] x = {10, 70, 130, 190, 250, 310, 370}; Integer[] y = {80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380};
    for (int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0; i < 42; i++, j++) {
        if (j % 7 == 0 && i != 0) { j = 0; k++; }
        lblCircles[i] = new JLabel("test");
        lblCircles[i].setBounds(x[j], y[k], 50, 50);
        lblCircles[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblCircles[i].setFont(big);
        lblCircles[i].setName("vuota");
        lblCircles[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                            if (e.getSource() == lblCircles[i] && choose == 1) lblClickedPlayer(lblCircles[i], j, k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(lblCircles[i]);
    }
}

public void baseFrame(JFrame baseFrame, int width, int height) {
    baseFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(41, 41, 41));
    baseFrame.setBounds(100, 100, width, height);
    baseFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    baseFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    baseFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    baseFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    baseFrame.setResizable(false);
    baseFrame.setVisible(true);
    baseFrame.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, baseFrame.getWidth(), baseFrame.getHeight(), 30, 30));
}

public void lblClickedPlayer(JLabel lbl, int r, int c) {
    if (n == 0 && "vuota".equals(lbl.getName())) {
        n = 1;
        lbl.setText("ok1");
        lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        lbl.setName("piena");
        tbl[r][c] = 1;
        System.out.println("tbl[" + r + "][" + c + "] = " + tbl[r][c]);
    } else if (n == 1 && "vuota".equals(lbl.getName())) {
        n = 0;
        lbl.setText("ok2");
        lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        lbl.setName("piena");
        tbl[r][c] = 2;
        System.out.println("tbl[" + r + "][" + c + "] = " + tbl[r][c]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For better help, please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.  Also a side note: to create a grid of JLabel, don't use `setBounds` and null layouts but rather a GridLayout.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: Which `if` are you referring to, there are two in your code?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki the two If in the lblClickedPlayer method.

Comment: How to test that since we can't run your code?

Comment: And you're not passing in a "matrix" but rather calling that `lblClickedPlayer(...)` method 42 times with each click.

Comment: Perhaps I confused what I wanted to do. I'm trying to call the lblClickedPlayer (...) method every time the player clicks a JLabel bringing the values ​​of 'j' and 'k' into the method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I entered the code for a test.

Comment: What do you mean "bringing the values of j and k into the method"? Again, the inner for loop is calling the method `for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {` nested with `for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {`  or 42 times, bringing in **all** values of j and k, from 0 to 6 combined with from 0 to 7. Are you trying to find out *which* label in the 2D array of labels has been pressed, the row and column number? If so, this isn't how you do it.

Comment: You must debug your programm runing it line by line and inspectig the state and the evolution of each variable. The way to accomplish it depends on your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc).

Comment: Also, how is your Prova test code not working? What is it not doing that you want it to do? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes ! I'm trying to do that, but I see that I've confused everything and I do not know how to get out of it anymore.

Comment: The Prova is working, but not like I want. I'm trying to pass 'j' and 'k' in the method lblClickedPlayer(), but without success.

Comment: @PacoAbato I'm using Eclipse, I debugged it but no errors, just wrong code I think.

Comment: Use debug step by step to see why your code behaves the way it does. Check the value of variables in each step so you can figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want those inner loops, since `i` is all you need. You can calculate the row and column from the i value easily by using int division and int remainder

```
    int r = i / COLS;
    int c = i % COLS;
```

For example

```
public class Prova {
    private static final int ROWS = 6;
    private static final int COLS = 7;

    // ....

            lblCircles[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                // better to use mousePressed, not mouseClicked
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    // no magic numbers such as 42 please. 
                    for (int i = 0; i < lblCircles.length; i++) {
                        if (e.getSource() == lblCircles[i] && choose == 1) {
                            myLabelClicked(lblCircles[i], i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

and

```
public void myLabelClicked(JLabel label, int i) {
    int r = i / COLS;
    int c = i % COLS;
    if (n == 0 && "vuota".equals(label.getName())) {
        n = 1;
        label.setText("ok1");
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        label.setName("piena");
        tbl[r][c] = 1;
    } else {
        n = 0;
        label.setText("ok2");
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        label.setName("piena");
        tbl[r][c] = 2;
    }
    System.out.println("tbl[" + r + "][" + c + "] = " + tbl[r][c]);
}
```

Side issues:

- Yes, much better using layout managers rather than setBounds, and so your second bit of code is better
- Avoid magic numbers such as `42` and instead use properties and constants.
- In my code above ROWS = 6 and COLS = 7

My MCVE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Prova2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROWS = 6;
    private static final int COLS = 7;
    private static final int LBL_EB = 25; // "eb" for empty border
    private static final int PNL_EB = 3;
    public static final Font BIG = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18);
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(41, 41, 41);
    private static final String VUOTA = "vuota";
    private JLabel[] lblCircles = new JLabel[ROWS * COLS];
    private Integer[][] tbl = new Integer[ROWS][COLS];
    private int choose = 1, n = 0;

    public Prova2() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(PNL_EB, PNL_EB, PNL_EB, PNL_EB));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        for (int i = 0; i < lblCircles.length; i++) {
            lblCircles[i] = new JLabel("test");
            lblCircles[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
            lblCircles[i].setFont(BIG);
            lblCircles[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(LBL_EB, LBL_EB, LBL_EB, LBL_EB));
            lblCircles[i].setName(VUOTA);
            lblCircles[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lblCircles.length; i++) {
                        if (e.getSource() == lblCircles[i] && choose == 1) {
                            myLabelClicked(lblCircles[i], i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            add(lblCircles[i]);
        }
    }

    protected void myLabelClicked(JLabel label, int i) {
        int row = i / COLS;
        int col = i % COLS;
        if (!VUOTA.equals(label.getName())) {
            return;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            n = 1;
            label.setText("ok1");
            tbl[row][col] = 1;
        } else {
            n = 0;
            label.setText("ok2");
            tbl[row][col] = 2;
        }
        label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        label.setName("piena");
        System.out.printf("tbl[%d][%d] = %d%n", row, col, tbl[row][col]);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Prova2 mainPanel = new Prova2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prova 2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, here was where I was wrong. Thank you so much, the code works correctly as I wanted.

Comment: @zAlweNy26: you're welcome. Please note changes made in my own MCVE, including using constants to make the code more self-commenting.